# What would the magento 2 equivalent of Mage::helper('core')->?

Tags: magento2, helper, mage

What would the magento 2 equivalent of Mage::helper('core')-> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mage` static methods are not existing anymore, you will have to use dependency injection to get your helper instance, for example in your model:

```
<?php
namespace Mycompany\Mymodule\Model;
use Mycompany\Mymodule\Helper\Data;
class Custom {

    private $helper;

    public function __construct(
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function myMethod() {
        $this->helper->helperMethod();
    }
}
```

You can use the same system in Blocks etc.. and for existing helpers that you want to use.